# I need to write a big-endian single-precision floating point number to file in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, endianness

I have a file format I'm trying to write to using C#.  The format encodes integer-based RGB color values as a floating point.  It also stores the values as big-endian.  I found an example of what I'm trying to do, written in php, here: http://www.colourlovers.com/ase.phps

I can convert the endian-ness easily.  I know this code is very verbose, but I'm just using it to watch the bits swap during troubleshooting.

```
    private uint SwapEndian(uint host) {
        uint ReturnValue;
        uint FirstHalf;
        uint LastHalf;
        FirstHalf = (host & 0xFFFF0000);
        FirstHalf = (FirstHalf >> 16);
        LastHalf = (host & 0x0000FFFF);
        LastHalf = (LastHalf << 16);
        ReturnValue = (FirstHalf | LastHalf);
        return ReturnValue;

    }
```

C# won't let me perform bit-shifts on floats.  Converting to an int or uint to call my SwapEndian method above loses the encoding information the file format requires.

So, how would you take a floating point number and change its endian-ness without losing the exponent data?

Comment: I've given an answer, but I'm not really sure where float figures in your example. Why not just treat as uint throughout?

Comment: The file format requires the RGB Value as a single-precision float.  The conspiracy theorist in me thinks it is to make the format harder to reverse-engineer: a straight int would be easy to find byte-wise with a hex editor.  If it was int/uint I'd be so much better off.

Comment: Given the link you provided me it looks like the standard, 1 = full color, 0 = none. Its not so much a conspiracy theory, but makes math easier ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just use:

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(floatVal);
```

And reverse the array (assuming the CPU is little-endian, which you an check), or simply just access the array in the order you need.

There is also a way to do this with unsafe code, treating the float* as a byte* so you can get the bytes in the order you want.

Answer (score 2):

I'm slightly confused as to why your shifting by 16 bits rather than 8. Naw do I understand why you need RGB as a float (they are generaly 1 byte each). But anywho.

you can use a 'fake' union to treat a float as an uint

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct FloatIntUnion
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]        
    public  float f;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public uint i;
}
```

this allows you to assign the `float` and then provide do bitwise operations on the `uint` part of the 'union' then use the `float` again as the final value.

However I would probably just use:

```
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes (RGB);
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse (bytes);
return bytes;
```

until performance started to become an issue (because of THIS method (read profile first)).

Comment: This is the format: http://www.selapa.net/swatches/colors/fileformats.php#adobe_ase